# webStack - A Stack Overflow Application for webOS

Tags: app, webos

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

webStack is my humble attempt to create an application for [webOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebOS) users that enables them to browse Stack Overflow questions, answers, users, etc.

#### License

webStack is released under the MIT license.

#### Download

I am completely new to webOS development, so hopefully this file is all I have to provide.

http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/webStack/com.mystuff.webstack_1.0.0_all.ipk

**Note: As you can see from the screenshot, I haven't really got anything done on it yet.** *I am posting this here so that people can see if what I have so far installs and displays properly.*

#### Platform

webOS

### Contact

I can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com

### Code

*Not yet available*

### Other

Please let me know if there are problems installing/using it.

Comment: George, please come over to the forums at developer.palm.com to get your questions answered.  We've got a big community over there, and people like me from Palm's developer relations group are monitoring and helping out.

Comment: @Ben: I heard that you had to sign up with a payment processor to get an account there. Is that true?

Comment: Hmmm... seems like it is :( Guess this app died before it even got a start.

Comment: Ah, yes, that works :)

Comment: @George since this never panned out, I ended up building my own WebOS client: http://stackapps.com/questions/1645/stacktacular-stackexchange-client-for-webos   I'd love to hear your opinion.

Comment: @TM: Great! I'll try it as soon as I can download it!