# Stacktacular: Stack Exchange client for WebOS

Tags: app, webos

### Screenshots

[image: Site list scene]
[image: Question list scene]
[image: Question scene]

### About

Stacktacular is a Stack Exchange client for [WebOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebOS). I created it mainly to scratch my own itch: viewing Stack Overflow using the phone browser was a bit painful, and no one had built a client for WebOS (that I could find).

The application is currently in beta, but it is pretty usable as far as viewing questions, answers and comments for the various Stack Exchange sites is concerned. I still plan to add a bunch of features regarding user management and watching.

#### License

Still determining this... probably will end up with the MIT license. The application source isn't public yet, but the application will be available for free on the [Palm App Catalog](http://mashable.com/2009/01/10/palm-app-catalog/).

#### Download

Opening http://developer.palm.com/appredirect/?packageid=com.taylormarshall.stacktacular  will take you directly to the App Catalog install page if viewed from a WebOS device, or will give you an option to "send to phone" if viewed in a regular browser.

#### Platform

WebOS, which is the operating system used on the Palm Pre / Palm Pixi smartphones.  **Note this has only been tested on WebOS 1.4 (Original Pre/Pixi).**  It may work on WebOS 2/3, but I haven't been working on any WebOS applications in about a year, so I haven't tested it there.

### Contact

This application was created by me (Taylor Marshall).

### Code

Stacktacular was written using JavaScript and HTML/CSS (WebOS SDK Framework) and the Ajax portions of jQuery.

**I'm interested in any feedback that people may have, thanks.**

Comment: looks pretty cool!

Answer (score 3):

It's great to finally see a WebOS Stack Exchange client!

Feature request:

- Add a "tagged questions" view. For example, one should be able to see only questions tagged "C++" on Stack Overflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b.

Comment: I'll add it to my "todo" list.  Please give me any other feedback you have.